# AWS cloudwatch cron event

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to setup a cloudwatch event which will get triggered in every X minutes, but should not be triggered at 0th minute. ie it should be triggered at current time+X minutes, 2X minutes, 3X minutes etc. How can i do that.

Update:  i had done setting up cloudwatch event, my only problem is crone expression. I want to get a cron expression which can schedule the event which start from 23rd minutes from the current time and at every 23rd minutes thereafter.

0/23 * * * ? *    doesnt work because it gets triggered at 0th minute
23/23 * * * ? *    doesnt work because 1st event may not be 23rd minutes apart from current time

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html ? If no - go for it, and if yes, what did you do and what exactly went wrong?

Comment: I followed the link, but my problem is it is getting executed in the 0th minute.
0/23 * * * ? *         Every 23 minutes it will get triggered but starting from 0th minute

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

You'll need to setup cloudwatch event for this. Here's the [link](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/schedule-lambda-on-cron-expression-triggers/) to it. You can further look at the cron expression using this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions). And, you can build the cron expression online using this [link](http://www.cronmaker.com).

The above mention links should fulfill your requirements.

Let me know if you need any further help. Thanks!

UPDATE:
As per your comments, following cron expression should fulfill your requirements. You can check by pasting this expression [here](http://www.cronmaker.com).

```
0 23/23 * * * ? *
```

Comment: but my problem is it is getting executed in the 0th minute. 0/23 * * * ? * Every 23 minutes it will get triggered but starting from 0th minute. I want to get the event triggered at 23rd minute from current timer

Comment: Thanks... i was able to do all these. But the problem is the cron expression. i want the event to get triggered after 23rd minutes from the current time and at every 23rd minutes thereafter... cron(0/23 * * * ? *) is getting triggered at 0th minute which i dont want.

Comment: Updated the answer with cron expression. @jayshankar

Comment: @jayshankar either you can use some script to setup cron dynamically. Otherwise cron job will always schedule based on your system time. You can use cron to trigger on specific minutes in an hour such as: 13,36,59 * * * ? *.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want the events to be triggered at every :23 and :46 minutes.

Here should be the correct cron expression:

```
23,46 * * * ? *
```

Comment: Thanks... i was able to do all these. But the problem is the cron expression. i want the event to get triggered after 23rd minutes from the current time and at every 23rd minutes thereafter...  cron(0/23 * * * ? *)  is getting triggered at 0th minute which i dont want.

Comment: @jayshankar Hi, I just added the correct cron expression to my answer which will remove the triggered 0th minute.